# Oracle DB Point In Time Recovery faulted

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, recovery, rman

I'm testing a procedure via RMAN backup to retore/recover at recover-point, but it fails.
Exactly I've executed the first time and it works:
Backup:

```
RMAN> backup database INCLUDE CURRENT CONTROLFILE format '/u01/app/oracle/keep_dir/bkp.%U' tag 'test_op2' keep until time 'sysdate+2' restore point 'pre_test_op2';
```

And restore/recover:

```
SQL> shutdown immediate;
SQL> startup nomount;
RMAN> set DBID 1024124299
RMAN> restore controlfile from '/u01/app/oracle/keep_dir/bkp.0dq3bfju_1_1';
RMAN> sql "alter database mount";
RMAN> restore database from TAG=TEST_OP2;
RMAN> RECOVER DATABASE;
RMAN> sql "alter database open resetlogs";
SQL> alter database open resetlogs
```

At the end incarnation list was the following:

`RMAN> list incarnation;`

```
List of Database Incarnations
DB Key  Inc Key DB Name  DB ID            STATUS  Reset SCN  Reset Time
------- ------- -------- ---------------- --- ---------- ----------
1       1       MYDB    1024124299       PARENT  1          17-SEP-11
2       2       MYDB    1024124299       PARENT  995548     21-FEB-15
3       3       MYDB    1024124299       CURRENT 1202973    01-APR-15
```

I've re-exeuted the backup:

```
RMAN> backup database INCLUDE CURRENT CONTROLFILE format '/u01/app/oracle/keep_dir/bkp.%U' tag 'test_op2' keep until time 'sysdate+2' restore point 'pre_test_op2';
```

Then I retry the procedure after that I modify DB, adding datafile and tablespace and removing other ones. 
Then I try to restore:

```
RMAN> set DBID 1024124299
RMAN> restore controlfile from '/u01/app/oracle/keep_dir/bkp.0dq3bfju_1_1';
RMAN> sql "alter database mount";
RMAN> restore database from TAG=TEST_OP2;
```

and the recover, but it fails:

```
RMAN> RECOVER DATABASE;

Starting recover at 02-APR-15
using channel ORA_DISK_1

starting media recovery

archived log for thread 1 with sequence 4 is already on disk as file /u01/app/oracle/fast_recovery_area/MYDB/archivelog/2015_04_02/o1_mf_1_4_bksxl25h_.arc
archived log for thread 1 with sequence 5 is already on disk as file /u01/app/oracle/oradata/MYDB/redo02.log
archived log file name=/u01/app/oracle/fast_recovery_area/MYDB/archivelog/2015_04_02/o1_mf_1_4_bksxl25h_.arc thread=1 sequence=4
archived log file name=/u01/app/oracle/oradata/MYDB/redo02.log thread=1 sequence=5
creating datafile file number=7 name=/u01/app/oracle/oradata/MYDB/MYDB/datafile/BSO_MYDB-PAR_20150402_000101.dbf
RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
RMAN-00569: =============== ERROR MESSAGE STACK FOLLOWS ===============
RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
RMAN-03002: failure of recover command at 04/02/2015 04:21:37
RMAN-11003: failure during parse/execution of SQL statement: alter database recover datafile list
 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 6 , 8 , 9 , 10 , 11
ORA-01179: file 10 does not exist
```

Listing the backup, it seems it lost a file:

```
RMAN> list backup;


List of Backup Sets
===================


BS Key  Type LV Size       Device Type Elapsed Time Completion Time
------- ---- -- ---------- ----------- ------------ ---------------
10      Full    1010.57M   DISK        00:00:48     02-APR-15
        BP Key: 10   Status: AVAILABLE  Compressed: NO  Tag: TEST_OP2
        Piece Name: /u01/app/oracle/keep_dir/bkp.0cq3bfi6_1_1
        Keep: BACKUP_LOGS        Until: 04-APR-15
  List of Datafiles in backup set 10
  File LV Type Ckp SCN    Ckp Time  Name
  ---- -- ---- ---------- --------- ----
  1       Full 1250240    02-APR-15 /u01/app/oracle/oradata/mydb/system01.dbf
  2       Full 1250240    02-APR-15 /u01/app/oracle/oradata/mydb/sysaux01.dbf
  3       Full 1250240    02-APR-15 /u01/app/oracle/oradata/mydb/undotbs01.dbf
  4       Full 1250240    02-APR-15 /u01/app/oracle/oradata/mydb/users01.dbf
  5       Full 1250240    02-APR-15 /u01/app/oracle/oradata/mydb/MYDB/datafile/o1_mf_bso_cfg__bgkz5vc3_.dbf
  6       Full 1250240    02-APR-15 /u01/app/oracle/oradata/mydb/MYDB/datafile/o1_mf_bso_cfg__bgkz9qy2_.dbf
  8       Full 1250240    02-APR-15 /u01/app/oracle/oradata/mydb/MYDB/datafile/BSO_MYDB-PAR2_20150221_1713.dbf
  9       Full 1250240    02-APR-15 /u01/app/oracle/oradata/mydb/MYDB/datafile/BSO_MYDB-PAR3_20150221_1713.dbf
  10      Full 1250240    02-APR-15
  11      Full 1250240    02-APR-15 /u01/app/oracle/oradata/mydb/MYDB/datafile/BSO_MYDB-PAR_20150401_100200.dbf
```

I don't understand which is the problem.
Can you help me?
Thanks,
 Ste

Answer (score 1):

Yes, following the backup output:

```
RMAN> list backup;


List of Backup Sets
===================


BS Key  Type LV Size       Device Type Elapsed Time Completion Time
------- ---- -- ---------- ----------- ------------ ---------------
10      Full    1010.57M   DISK        00:00:48     02-APR-15
        BP Key: 10   Status: AVAILABLE  Compressed: NO  Tag: TEST_OP2
        Piece Name: /u01/app/oracle/keep_dir/bkp.0cq3bfi6_1_1
        Keep: BACKUP_LOGS        Until: 04-APR-15
  List of Datafiles in backup set 10
  File LV Type Ckp SCN    Ckp Time  Name
  ---- -- ---- ---------- --------- ----
  1       Full 1250240    02-APR-15 /u01/app/oracle/oradata/MYDB/system01.dbf
  2       Full 1250240    02-APR-15 /u01/app/oracle/oradata/MYDB/sysaux01.dbf
  3       Full 1250240    02-APR-15 /u01/app/oracle/oradata/MYDB/undotbs01.dbf
  4       Full 1250240    02-APR-15 /u01/app/oracle/oradata/MYDB/users01.dbf
  5       Full 1250240    02-APR-15 /u01/app/oracle/oradata/MYDB/MYDB/datafile/o1_mf_bso_cfg__bgkz5vc3_.dbf
  6       Full 1250240    02-APR-15 /u01/app/oracle/oradata/MYDB/MYDB/datafile/o1_mf_bso_cfg__bgkz9qy2_.dbf
  8       Full 1250240    02-APR-15 /u01/app/oracle/oradata/MYDB/MYDB/datafile/BSO_MYDB-PAR2_20150221_1713.dbf
  9       Full 1250240    02-APR-15 /u01/app/oracle/oradata/MYDB/MYDB/datafile/BSO_MYDB-PAR3_20150221_1713.dbf
  10      Full 1250240    02-APR-15 /u01/app/oracle/oradata/MYDB/MYDB/datafile/BSO_MYDB-PAR_20150401_100100.dbf
  11      Full 1250240    02-APR-15 /u01/app/oracle/oradata/MYDB/MYDB/datafile/BSO_MYDB-PAR_20150401_100200.dbf

BS Key  Type LV Size       Device Type Elapsed Time Completion Time
------- ---- -- ---------- ----------- ------------ ---------------
11      Full    9.33M      DISK        00:00:01     02-APR-15
        BP Key: 11   Status: AVAILABLE  Compressed: NO  Tag: TEST_OP2
        Piece Name: /u01/app/oracle/keep_dir/bkp.0dq3bfju_1_1
        Keep: BACKUP_LOGS        Until: 04-APR-15
  Control File Included: Ckp SCN: 1250258      Ckp time: 02-APR-15

BS Key  Type LV Size       Device Type Elapsed Time Completion Time
------- ---- -- ---------- ----------- ------------ ---------------
12      Full    80.00K     DISK        00:00:01     02-APR-15
        BP Key: 12   Status: AVAILABLE  Compressed: NO  Tag: TEST_OP2
        Piece Name: /u01/app/oracle/keep_dir/bkp.0eq3bfk0_1_1
        Keep: BACKUP_LOGS        Until: 04-APR-15
  SPFILE Included: Modification time: 02-APR-15
  SPFILE db_unique_name: MYDB

BS Key  Size       Device Type Elapsed Time Completion Time
------- ---------- ----------- ------------ ---------------
13      4.00K      DISK        00:00:00     02-APR-15
        BP Key: 13   Status: AVAILABLE  Compressed: NO  Tag: TEST_OP2
        Piece Name: /u01/app/oracle/keep_dir/bkp.0fq3bfk2_1_1
        Keep: BACKUP_LOGS        Until: 04-APR-15

  List of Archived Logs in backup set 13
  Thrd Seq     Low SCN    Low Time  Next SCN   Next Time
  ---- ------- ---------- --------- ---------- ---------
  1    4       1250236    02-APR-15 1250273    02-APR-15

BS Key  Type LV Size       Device Type Elapsed Time Completion Time
------- ---- -- ---------- ----------- ------------ ---------------
14      Full    9.33M      DISK        00:00:01     02-APR-15
        BP Key: 14   Status: AVAILABLE  Compressed: NO  Tag: TEST_OP2
        Piece Name: /u01/app/oracle/keep_dir/bkp.0gq3bfk3_1_1
        Keep: BACKUP_LOGS        Until: 04-APR-15
  Control File Included: Ckp SCN: 1250278      Ckp time: 02-APR-15
```

The file 10 is part of the same backup piece of the other ones.

```
vm-sles11-node3:~ # ll /u01/app/oracle/keep_dir/bkp.0cq3bfi6_1_1
-rw-r----- 1 oracle oinstall 1059667968 Apr  2 03:56 /u01/app/oracle/keep_dir/bkp.0cq3bfi6_1_1
```